# How to Group by with Count and Join?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, A(ID, Name), B(ID).
I want record with group by Name, and count of A(ID) and B(ID)

I am trying this way

```
SELECT LEFT(OD.number, 3)        Terminal, 
       Count(LEFT(OD.number, 2)) OrderCount, 
       Count(OT.orderid) 
FROM   gff_bog_orderlocation.dbo.orderdetail OD, 
       gff_bog_orderlocation.dbo.ordertable OT 
WHERE  OT.orderid IN (SELECT orderid 
                      FROM   gff_bog_orderlocation.dbo.orderdetail 
                      WHERE  LEFT(number, 3) IN(SELECT LEFT(number, 3) 
                                                FROM 
                             gff_bog_orderlocation.dbo.orderdetail 
                                                GROUP  BY LEFT(number, 3))) 
GROUP  BY LEFT(OD.number, 3) 
ORDER  BY terminal
```

But I am not getting properly.

Comment: @psoshmo He did show what he tried.  He explained why he was stuck.  That said, the question still makes no sense.  How does table `A` even relate to table `B`?  What are you trying to get out of this query...?

Comment: @Siyual sorry the bad formatting at first made my eyes glaze over and miss the obvious attempt. Ill delete my comment

Answer (score 1):

based on your question and not your sql i'd say you'd need to do something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE TableB (ID INT)
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1, 'US'), (2, 'US'), (3, 'Canada'), (4, 'Mexico'), (5, 'Mexico')
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (1), (1), (1), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3), (4), (4), (4), (5), (5), (5), (5), (5) 

SELECT tA.Name,
       COUNT(*) TableACount,
       TableBCount
FROM   TableA tA
        JOIN (
            SELECT Name,
                   COUNT(*) TableBCount
            FROM   TableA tA
                   LEFT JOIN TableB tB ON tA.ID = tB.ID 
            GROUP BY    
                   Name 
        ) tB ON tA.Name = tB.Name
GROUP BY tA.Name,
        TableBCount

DROP TABLE TableA
DROP TABLE TableB

RESULT: 

Name    TableACount TableBCount
----    ----------- -----------
Canada  1           3
Mexico  2           8
US      2           5
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted, but was not clear with my question.